# How to add pages in wordpress using codes?

Tags: theme-development, pages, page-template

I am trying to add wordpress pages using codes on theme activation. But the main problem is i cannot check whether the page with that particular slugs exist or not.

Our code looks like this :

```
add_action("after_switch_theme",function(){
    if(is_page('all-post-list')){
        return;
    }else{
        wp_insert_post(['post_title' =>'List Of All the Posts','post_status'=>'publish','post_name'=>'all-post-list','post_type'=>'page','page_template'=>'All Post List']);
        return;
    }
});
```

This hook is inserted in custom hook.

The main problem is with is_page

it is not working .

when i `var_dump(is_page('all-post-list'))` it always return false although there are pages.

But when i `var dump that` in `header.php` it works as expected.

Why is not that working in php . From Codex i read the note of using is_page and the code is outside loop then why is it nor working?

Is there any workaround??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`is_page()` checks if page is being *displayed*, it has nothing to do with checking if page *exists at all* in installation.

You likely want [`get_page_by_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_path/) or [`get_page_by_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) instead.